# systemctl error in docker 'Failed to connect to bus: No such file or directory'

Tags: docker, chef-infra, cookbook, test-kitchen, systemctl

I am using *Ubuntu-16.04* image with **docker** to test my cookbook in local. While doing `kitchen converge`, I am getting the following error. I figured out `systemctl` is not working properly. Can someone please help me to fix this problem *OR* any other way to achieve the same thing?

```
 [2017-11-30T15:22:30+00:00] INFO: Running queued delayed notifications before re-raising exception

 Running handlers:
   [2017-11-30T15:22:30+00:00] ERROR: Running exception handlers
   Running handlers complete
   [2017-11-30T15:22:30+00:00] ERROR: Exception handlers complete
   Chef Client failed. 9 resources updated in 06 seconds
   [2017-11-30T15:22:30+00:00] FATAL: Stacktrace dumped to /tmp/kitchen/cache/chef-stacktrace.out
   [2017-11-30T15:22:30+00:00] FATAL: Please provide the contents of the stacktrace.out file if you file a bug report
   [2017-11-30T15:22:30+00:00] ERROR: envoy_auth_apps_setup[default-service] (envoy_auth_apps::_default line 1) had an error: Chef::Exceptions::MultipleFailures: Multiple failures occurred:
   * Mixlib::ShellOut::ShellCommandFailed occurred in chef run: execute[systemctl daemon-reload] (/tmp/kitchen/cache/cookbooks/envoy_auth_apps/resources/setup.rb line 133) had an error: Mixlib::ShellOut::ShellCommandFailed: Expected process to exit with [0], but received '1'
   ---- Begin output of systemctl daemon-reload ----
   STDOUT:
   STDERR: Failed to connect to bus: No such file or directory
   ---- End output of systemctl daemon-reload ----
   Ran systemctl daemon-reload returned 1
   * Mixlib::ShellOut::ShellCommandFailed occurred in delayed notification: service[envoy] (/tmp/kitchen/cache/cookbooks/envoy_auth_apps/resources/setup.rb line 194) had an error: Mixlib::ShellOut::ShellCommandFailed: Expected process to exit with [0], but received '1'
   ---- Begin output of /bin/systemctl --system restart envoy ----
   STDOUT:
   STDERR: Failed to connect to bus: No such file or directory
   ---- End output of /bin/systemctl --system restart envoy ----
   Ran /bin/systemctl --system restart envoy returned 1

   [2017-11-30T15:22:30+00:00] FATAL: Chef::Exceptions::ChildConvergeError: Chef run process exited unsuccessfully (exit code 1)
 >>>>>> ------Exception-------
 >>>>>> Class: Kitchen::ActionFailed
 >>>>>> Message: 1 actions failed.
 >>>>>>     Converge failed on instance <default-ubuntu>.  Please see .kitchen/logs/default-ubuntu.log for more details
 >>>>>> ----------------------
 >>>>>> Please see .kitchen/logs/kitchen.log for more details
 >>>>>> Also try running `kitchen diagnose --all` for configuration
```

This is my `.kitchen.yml`

```
---

driver:
  name: docker
  binary: /usr/local/bin/docker
  use_sudo: false
  network:
    - ["public_network", "bridge: 'en0: Wi-Fi (AirPort)'"]

provisioner:
  name: chef_zero
  require_chef_omnibus: "12.21.14"
  environments_path: test/integration/environments
  nodes_path: test/integration/nodes
  data_bags_path: test/integration/data_bags
  client_rb:
    environment: development

verifier:
  name: inspec

platforms:
  - name: ubuntu
    driver_config:
      image: ubuntu:xenial
      platform: ubuntu
#     provision_command:
#       - apt-get -y install dbus

suites:
  - name: default
    run_list:
#   - recipe[base_app]
        - recipe[envoy_auth_apps::_default]
    verifier:
      inspec_tests:
        - test/integration/default
attributes:
  nameserver:
    domain_name: 'kitchen.xyz.io'
  envoy_auth_apps:
    consul_client_enabled: false
```

Comment: systemctl only works if you're running systemd, and using systemd in a docker container is not a particularly good idea -- the Docker Way is to directly invoke the single service that container is supposed to run, rather than having an init system in each container.

Answer (score 3):

Normally docker doesn't support `systemd` services in container, but you can use a special [ubuntu systemd](https://hub.docker.com/r/solita/ubuntu-systemd/) image with some additional host configuration. Note that this image **is not recommended** to be run in production.

Firstly, you need to setup your host to be able to run this image:

`docker run --rm --privileged -v /:/host solita/ubuntu-systemd setup`

Then, you'll be able to run containers with `systemd` (adding necessary mounts and flags):

```
docker run -d --name systemd --security-opt seccomp=unconfined \
 --tmpfs /run --tmpfs /run/lock -v /sys/fs/cgroup:/sys/fs/cgroup:ro \
 -t solita/ubuntu-systemd
```

Comment: Test Kitchen is an integration test suite, not a production system :)

Comment: I tried with ``ubuntu-systemd`` image but its not working. Giving the same error as I shown above. This image is for **systemd** but in my case it's 
 **systemctl**. Is it the problem?

Comment: **systemd** is an init system and system manager while **systemctl** is a command line tool to manage systemd services. I've added some editions which can help you to achieve your goal.

Comment: Actually, systemctl uses d-bus to talk to the systemd daemon which in turn manages the services. The systemctl tool itself is pretty dumb.

Answer (score 3):

`kitchen-docker` is not really set up to work with systemd. I would recommend using `kitchen-dokken` instead, which is fairly easy to set up this way.

Answer (score 0):

YES, there is another way to achieve the same thing! You can try to replace the standard systemd systemctl with the https://github.com/gdraheim/docker-systemctl-replacement ... while it works in surprising number of environments, it has not been tested so far with kitchen. Please provide some feedback if you're giving it a try.