# Stop service running inside a docker container without stopping the whole container

Tags: docker, service, couchbase

I have a docker container running Couchbase, and I need to perform an operation on it that requires the couchbase-server service to temporarily stop.
This is required to overwrite some configuration files within the container. Operation steps are described below.

```sh
docker exec -it "bumblebase" bash -c "systemctl stop couchbase-server"

docker exec -it "bumblebase" bash -c "echo \"{rest_port, 3456}.\" >> \"/opt/couchbase/etc/couchbase/static_config\""

docker exec -it "bumblebase" bash -c "rm -rf /opt/couchbase/var/lib/couchbase/config/config.dat"

docker exec -it "bumblebase" bash -c "systemctl start couchbase-server"
```

Running this gives me the following error ;

```sh
Failed to connect to bus: No such file or directory
```

I only found one workaround for it, from the [following stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47577752/9021186). However, I am not fine with modifying couchbase default image, plus the alternate image is marked as unmaintend for a while now.

I also tried this alternate command from [couchbase documentation](https://docs.couchbase.com/server/current/install/startup-shutdown.html) :

```sh
docker exec -it "bumblebase" bash -c "service couchbase-server stop"
```

But then I have another error :

```sh
couchbase-server: unrecognized service
```

I just want the couchbase-server service to stop within the container, is it possible ? Or is it an alternative solution to overwrite my config files ?

Comment: We usually don't run `systemd` to keep applications running inside containers. You'll probably need to stop the container to perform your changes (probably in a external volume). Do you mind sharing the base image that you're using?

Comment: @GustavoKawamoto I'm using the official Couchbase Community image https://github.com/couchbase/docker/blob/78cbcaa2c90ce4c975299e7cbfdce146a7bab081/community/couchbase-server/6.6.0/Dockerfile

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't usually stop processes in a container, separately from stopping the whole container itself.  In this situation it's pretty common to delete and recreate the container, in fact.  Correspondingly, you shouldn't use `docker exec` to edit files inside a container; that would get lost on a routine restart.

If you don't already, you can copy the config file out of the container

```sh
docker cp bumblebase:/opt/couchbase/etc/couchbase/static_config .
```

Now you can edit the local copy of the config file, using your choice of editor.

Finally, you can stop, delete, and recreate the container.  The `docker run -v` option can inject individual config files into the container.

```sh
docker stop bumblebase
docker rm bumblebase
docker run \
  -d \
  -p 8091-8094:8091-8094 -p 11210:11210 \
  --name bumblebase \
  -v $PWD/static_config:/opt/couchbase/etc/couchbase/static_config \
  couchbase:community-6.6.0
```

For a couple of reasons, commands like `service` or `systemctl` basically don't work in Docker at all.  Generally the server process a container runs is a foreground process that runs as the main container process; there isn't an init system or any background processes, and if the server process exits, the container will exit with it.

Comment: I was able to successfully write the config file by launching the container using your solution. Sadly I run into another problem which is by doing this, I cannot access at all couchbase anymore. It comes back if I remove the -v option (but then again I'm stuck at the starting point, which is I cannot set my custom ports from within the container). I have a separate post I'll update in that regard. At least this solved my issue of modifying configuration files :)

Answer (score 0):

Also you can mount config file from host to container, edit config file and just restart container